# If a product is normal, are all of its partial products also normal?

Tags: general-topology

It seems like this should be true, but I can't find the right argument.  Thanks.

Edit: How about

1) Take two disjoint closed sets in a partial product.

2) Extend them trivially to the entire product.

3) Separate them with disjoint open sets in the big product.

4) Restrict these open sets to the subproduct.  ???

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X_i)_I$ be topological spaces. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint closed sets in $X_j$ then their preimages $p_j^{-1}(A_{1,2})$ are disjoint. They are also closed since the projections are open continuous maps. In fact, for every continuous open map preimage commutes with closure. By normality, there are disjoint open neighborhood $U_1, U_2$. For every $i\neq j$ fix an element $x_i\in X_i$. Then $X^*=\bigcap_{i\neq j}p_i^{-1}(x_i)$ is homeomorphic to $X_j$. Then $U_1\cap X^*$ and $U_2\cap X^*$ are open and disjoint in $X^*$, so their projections onto $X_j$ are open disjoint sets containing $A_1$ and $A_2$, respectively.

Comment: Ok, I see how this will imply that each of the factors is normal.  And then for a partial product, just combine this with the steps I outlined above?

Comment: @DavidL. Sorry, I discovered a mistake which came from generalizing this from two factors two arbitrary many. It is even easier than I thought. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Are projection maps really open? This would imply they are closed, and I think there are theorems where you have to prove the projection maps are closed, based on some nontrivial set of assumptions.  For instance, an arbitrary product is pseudocompact iff each of its factors is pseudocompact and the projections map zero sets to closed sets.

Comment: @DavidL. No open does not imply closed, only with bijections you can do so. Projections are indeed open. To see this, you just need to show that the image of an open basis set (a box) is open. They are not closed, for example the closed graph of the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ in $\mathbb R^2$ projected onto the $x$-axis gives $\mathbb R-\{0\}$. On the other hand, if $Y$ is compact, then the projection $Y\times X\to X$ is closed.